# why i get this error from my code its say the data type mismatch in criteria expression

Tags: vb.net

im trying to change values on my database with this code and its say the data type mismatch in criteria expression i know its from quote or something else but it seems i cant find it so can you guys help me, all the data type i am using is text (i am using ms accses here) only DTPTanggalLahir using date type bersih() is to clear all thing in form and isiGrid() is to refrest my datagridview

```
Private Sub BTUbah_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTUbah.Click
    Try
        Call KONEKSI()
        ubah = "UPDATE Siswa SET nis='" & TBNIS.Text & "',nama='" & TBNama.Text & "',tempat_lahir='" & TBTempatLahir.Text & "',tanggal_lahir='" & DTPTanggalLahir.Text & "',jenis_kelamin='" & CBJenisKelamin.Text & "',alamat='" & TBAlamat.Text & "' WHERE nis = '" & TBNIS.Text & "'"
        CMD = CONN.CreateCommand
        With CMD
            .CommandText = ubah
            .Connection = CONN
            .Parameters.Add("p1", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = TBNIS.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p2", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = TBNama.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p3", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = TBTempatLahir.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p4", OleDbType.Date, 100).Value = DTPTanggalLahir.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p5", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = CBJenisKelamin.Text
            .Parameters.Add("p6", OleDbType.Char, 20).Value = TBAlamat.Text
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
        Dim pilihan = MessageBox.Show("Apakah anda yakin?", "PERINGATAN!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
        If pilihan = DialogResult.Yes Then
            Call bersih()
            Call isiGrid()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("TERJADI KESALAHAN", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "KESALAHAN")
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You will have to choose between string Concatenation and Parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The `p4` parameter is of type `OleDbType.Date` so you should better assign it a `DateTime` value, i.e. use `DTPTanggalLahir.Value` instead of `DTPTanggalLahir.Text`.

Not related to the error under question but should be noted anyway. In order to construct a parametrized query use `@param_name` placeholder instead of injecting the value directly by concatenation. In your case the query might look as follows:

```
ubah = "UPDATE Siswa SET nis=@p1, nama=@p2, tempat_lahir=@p3, tanggal_lahir=@p4, jenis_kelamin=@p5, alamat=@p6 WHERE nis = @p1"
```